# Update figure while waiting for event in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to be able to set parameters in a program in real time in Matlab using mouse input. I have video playing continuously in one figure, and I'd like to be able to click on certain points in that figure to update. However, when I call `ginput`, the figure stops updating until I click. Right now my code looks something like this:

```
while 1
    frame = step(FrameReader);
    image(frame);
    [x,y] = ginput(1);
    pause(0.1);
end
```

Is there another way to introduce a mouse click listener to a figure than using `ginput`, or another way to call `ginput` that will allow the movie to run seamlessly in the background?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546499/matlab-buttondownfcn

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'ButtonDownFcn'` property (of the figure or axes) as mentioned by [grantnz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350550/grantnz). [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html) is more handy when there is a non real-time task.

First of all, note that high level functions such as [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html), [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html), [`image`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html) etc, will reset most of the axes properties such as `'HitTest'` and `'ButtonDownFcn'`. Thus after each time you use such functions you should **update** the required **axes handle properties**. In general you should avoid using such high level functions in a high frequency loop for better performance.

In addition to setting **`'ButtonDownFcn'` of the axes** implied by [grantnz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350550/grantnz) you can use the **`'ButtonDownFcn'` of the figure**. *Note* that in second case you should turn off the selectability of the axes (set `'HitTest'` of axes to `Off`).

Here is a dummy animation, in which you can click on the animated axes and see the `'CurrentPoint'` of the axes.

```
% Stop button
uicontrol(...
    'Style','pushbutton', 'String', 'Stop',...
    'Units','Normalized', 'Position', [0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1],...
    'Callback', 'run = 0;');

% Axes
ax = axes(...
    'Units','Normalized',...
    'OuterPosition', [0 0.2 1 0.8]);

run = 1;
t = 0;
while run
    t = t + 0.01; x = t:0.01:t+2;
    h = plot(ax, x, sin(x));
    set(ax, 'ButtonDownFcn', 'get(ax, ''CurrentPoint'')');
    xlim([x(1) x(end)]); ylim([-1 1]);
    pause(0.01);
end
```

*Note* that `'ButtonDownFcn'` is updated each time after [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html).

It's also possible to get the `'CurrentPoint'` of the figure, if so, you should set `Normalized` units for figure to get the normalized position of `'CurrentPoint'`.