# Running ginput while also running a loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ginput

I want to display a crosshair in one of the games I'm making in MATLAB.  I tried using the ginput because it would be perfect as it displays crosshairs and reads in the x and y locations of what was clicked.  However, since it always waits for a click and I have moving objects, it causes the object to be created on the screen and then not move.  How do I get the loop to run and continue moving the object while ginput is also running and evaluating clicks?

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to [Update figure while waiting for event in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458920/update-figure-while-waiting-for-event-in-matlab)

To summarize: ginput is not good for real time interactive functions and really more of an annotation tool. Look at the `ButtonDownFcn` property of the figure. The link also includes a small example of how you would implement something like this. I will copy here for clarity but original credit goes to [pm89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1698972/pm89) and [grantnz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350550/grantnz)

```
% Stop button
uicontrol(...
    'Style','pushbutton', 'String', 'Stop',...
    'Units','Normalized', 'Position', [0.4 0.1 0.2 0.1],...
    'Callback', 'run = 0;');

% Axes
ax = axes(...
    'Units','Normalized',...
    'OuterPosition', [0 0.2 1 0.8]);

run = 1;
t = 0;
while run
    t = t + 0.01; x = t:0.01:t+2;
    h = plot(ax, x, sin(x));
    set(ax, 'ButtonDownFcn', 'get(ax, ''CurrentPoint'')');
    xlim([x(1) x(end)]); ylim([-1 1]);
    pause(0.01);
end
```

Comment: So does this display the crosshairs?  That is mainly all I'm trying to get out of the ginput function

Comment: @user3586897 This code covers the clicking functionality. For displaying the cursor you would have to do something like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1758-crosshairs-or-just-vertical-line-across-linked-axis-plots)